# Page display certain Category Posts

Tags: categories, page-template

I want to do almost exactly this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#A_Page_of_Posts

But Im confused by the last line:

> Save this to pageofposts.php and then assign PageofPosts as the
>   Template when creating the action Page:

How do I tell Wordpress to go to index.php, (or anything else) when, for example, it receives an 'events' slug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read more on [how to use page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates)

Comment: thanks figured it out.  You can set the template under the 'Appearance' tab